# How to add employee name and employee id on same line using CSS and html?

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I work on asp.net MVC app . I face issue on add employee id and employee name on same line
exactly as web design attached .

so I need to modify script using html and CSS to add

Emp.ID  and رقم الموظف and Emp.Name And اسم الموظف on same line

my issue I can't add employee id and employee name on same line so

How to make that please ?

code details what I try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Your custom CSS -->
    <style>
    .form-header {
text-align: center;
width: 30%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: 
gray;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
padding: 20px;
}

.form-header h2 {
color: 
white;
margin: 0;
}

.form-container {
  background-color: 
#eee;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid 
#ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-section {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width:400px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid 
#ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.fill-by-employee {
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  color: 
#888;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea,
input[type="date"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: 
#4CAF50;
  color: 
white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: 
#45a049;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="form-header"> <h2> نموذج تسجيل استقاله <br/> Resignation Submission Form</h2> </div>
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form-section">
    <label for="emp-input">Filled By Employee:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <p class="fill-by-employee">يتم ملئها من الموظف</p>
  </div>
</div>
   <form>
      <div class="employee-info">
        <label for="emp-id">Emp. ID:</label>
        <label for="emp-id">-----</label>

        <label for="dept-branch">رقم الموظف:</label>
         <label for="dept-branch">----</label>

        <label for="submission-date">Emp Name:</label>
        <label for="submission-date">------</label>

        <label for="emp-sign">اسم الموظف:</label>
        <label for="emp-sign">-----</label>
      </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Add employee id and employee name]

**update post**

answer solved my question but without add borders s image attached
can you please modified code attached by add border on left and right and bottom and top exactly as image please

Comment: You may like to look into css flexbox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#the_flex_model

Comment: can you please modified code attached by add border on left and right and bottom and top exactly as image please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your labels to have `display: inline-block`

```css
.employee-info > label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Your custom CSS -->
    <style>
    .form-header {
text-align: center;
width: 30%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: 
gray;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
padding: 20px;
}

.form-header h2 {
color: 
white;
margin: 0;
}

.form-container {
  background-color: 
#eee;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid 
#ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-section {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width:400px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid 
#ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.fill-by-employee {
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  color: 
#888;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea,
input[type="date"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: 
#4CAF50;
  color: 
white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: 
#45a049;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="form-header"> <h2> نموذج تسجيل استقاله <br/> Resignation Submission Form</h2> </div>
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form-section">
    <label for="emp-input">Filled By Employee:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <p class="fill-by-employee">يتم ملئها من الموظف</p>
  </div>
</div>
   <form>
      <div class="employee-info">
        <label for="emp-id">Emp. ID:</label>
        <label for="emp-id">-----</label>

        <label for="dept-branch">رقم الموظف:</label>
         <label for="dept-branch">----</label>

        <label for="submission-date">Emp Name:</label>
        <label for="submission-date">------</label>

        <label for="emp-sign">اسم الموظف:</label>
        <label for="emp-sign">-----</label>
      </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like this, group the elements in a div and use flexbox to layout design. I have put inline styles so you can better understand.

```css
.form-header {
  color: black;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.form-header h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.form-container {
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  border-bottom: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-info {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.employee-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.id_container,
.name_container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.table-border-end {
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 2px dashed gray;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed gray;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea,
input[type="date"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-header">
  <h2>
    نموذج تسجيل استقاله <br /> Resignation Submission Form
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form-info">
    <div class="form-section">
      <label for="emp-input">To be filled by the Employee</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-section">
      <p class="fill-by-employee">يتم ملئها من الموظف</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <div class="employee-info">
        <div class="id_container">
          <label for="emp-id">Emp. ID:</label>
          <label for="emp-id">-----</label>

          <label for="dept-branch">رقم الموظف:</label>
          <label for="dept-branch">----</label>
        </div>

        <div class="name_container">
          <label for="submission-date">Emp Name:</label>
          <label for="submission-date">------</label>

          <label for="emp-sign">اسم الموظف:</label>
          <label for="emp-sign">-----</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="table-border-end"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how to add borders on all sides as image attached original post

Comment: Chekout CSS border property. You can do something like border: 1px dotted black. Meaning dotted border of 1px width in black color.

Comment: can you show me how to add it please to my script

Comment: Check edit, I have made it similar to the image you mentioned.